# Enzyme typescript – Cannot set property target of [object Event] which has only a getter at Function.assign

Tags: typescript, enzyme, preact

code:

```
...
wrapper.find('input').simulate('input', { target: {value: 's'}})
```

cmd:

```
jest test
```

result

```
Cannot set property target of [object Event] which has only a getter at Function.assign
```

Error in node_modules/enzyme-adapter-preact-pure/build/src/MountRenderer.js

```
    var event = new Event(eventName, {
        bubbles: args.bubbles,
        composed: args.composed,
        cancelable: args.cancelable,
    });
    Object.assign(event, args);
```

Event is interface from typescript/libs/lib.d.ts

```
interface Event {
    ...
    readonly target: EventTarget | null;
    ...
}
```

target is **readonly**, how set custom target?

package.json

```
"@types/jest": "^24.0.19",
"@types/jquery": "^3.3.31",
"enzyme": "^3.10.0",
"enzyme-adapter-preact-pure": "^2.1.0",
"enzyme-to-json": "^3.4.3",
"jest": "^24.9.0",
"preact": "^8.4.2",
"preact-context": "^1.1.4",
"preact-redux": "^2.0.3",
"redux": "^4.0.1",
"ts-jest": "^24.1.0",
"ts-loader": "^4.5.0",
"typescript": "^3.5.3",
"webpack": "^4.39.1",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.9"
```